# Json Serialize property with private getter

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I store C# domain objects for caching in a RedisDB. These objects have properties with `private getter` and `private setter`.

`Private setter` is fixed with a custom `ContractResolver` where I set the property to `Writable = true` and it works.

Now I have the same problem with private getters. These properties are not serialized and therefore not stored.

Is there similar way to make the private properties Readable for the serialization?

Here the class and the enum FIXED

```
[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
    [DataMember]
    public Applicability Applicability { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public CustomerRole Role { private get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public enum CustomerRole
{
    EmployeeOrAgent,
    AircraftOperator,
    NominatedRepairOrganization,
    ThirdPartyRepairOrganization,
    AirworthinessAuthority
}
```

Comment: Can you share the class that your are trying to serialize?

Comment: Did you try putting DataContract/DataMember attributes on?

Comment: That has fixed it! If you put it in an answer I mark it as solution